# Can I use AWS as a virtual computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know zilch about AWS, and everything I read about it is at a level of generality beyond my poor understanding.

So, to be specific, say I plan a peripatetic lifestyle. Or say I cross national borders frequently with an ever-present danger of having my laptop confiscated.

Can I keep only a barebones laptop computer locally, and put compilers (say perl, python, etc), editors, browsers and my own programs and data on AWS, edit my code and run it on AWS, and then view the output on my laptop from wherever I may be?

Does AWS provide any of these programs as a service, so I don't have to upload them?

Comment: Simple answer: yes. Anything you do with VMWare you could essentially do with AWS and their services. I use AWS EC2 and other features for services, including databases, simple storage (S3), amongst a number of other things. AWS should be able to do nearly everything you're looking for when it comes to computing, compiling, and so on.

Comment: But where your big effort will come is getting everything set up correctly along with permissions, ports, and such. You may also want to become familiar with the AWS CLI tool. And check out the SDKs available in a number of different languages. In some cases you may even have to do some custom coding to get things exactly the way you want them.

Comment: not 100% if this is what you want, but https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/ looks to already be a thing

Comment: there are also a lot of other services available that provide things like this, just search for "virtual desktop service" or similar

Answer (score 3):

Amazon WorkSpaces may have the functionality you are looking for.

https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/?nc2=h_m1

There is a free trial version to test it out.

Comment: Upvote. If you do not know much about AWS and you just want a secure desktop in the cloud that you connect to from your laptop, then this is a good answer. I have used Amazon WorkSpaces for just this purpose. The key difference between WorkSpaces and EC2 is that WorkSpaces supports a Windows desktop - EC2 does not.

Comment: To clarify: Workspaces provides a Windows 10 desktop. Amazon EC2 provides Windows Server.

Comment: Furthermore, there are WorkSpaces clients for Window, Mac, Android, iOS and even web browser. Very accessible.